# Google Maps listener does not work in `d3.csv()`

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a map in Google Maps Javascript API that uses D3.js to read in data. When a user clicks a circle, `console.log()` should display information from that datapoint.

```
function initMap(){
    var mapObj = {};
    $.getJSON("data/Base GMap style.json",function(GMapBaseStyle){
        var map = new google.maps.Map("map-element", {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});

        d3.csv("data.csv").then(function(data){
            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var d = data[i];

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: {
                        d["lat"],
                        d["lon"]
                    }
                });

                circle.addListener("click",function(event){
                    console.log(d)
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The circles appear in the correct coordinates but when I click each one, `console.log()` prints  `d` for the last element of `data` in the `for` loop.

How do I set this up so that `console.log()` prints the correct `d`?

Answer (score -2):

I changed

`var d = data[i];`

to this:

`let d = data[i];`